# Should a "catch" block and rollback() inside it be always included for all transactions?

Tags: java, hibernate, rollback

Well, I saw the the following code on jboss.org
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html

A typical transaction should use the following idiom:

```
Session sess = factory.openSession();
 Transaction tx;
 try {
     tx = sess.beginTransaction();
     //do some work
     ...
     tx.commit();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
     if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
     throw e;
 }
 finally {
     sess.close();
 }
```

Should the rollback statement be included if "my work" was just reading from the db (e.g. something like users = session.createQuery("from User").getResultList();) or can I just omit the "catch" code?
The same question if I'm changing something in the db, like "session.delete(session.get(User.class, id))"?

In my opinion, if there is an exception during the operation, the update will not be done. And since it's only one operation, there will be nothing to rollback. Should rollback() be included in the code in this case? What sense of it if it was just one operation?

I tried to find some explanations on when rollback() is really needed on the web and docs but unfortunately didn't succeed. I personally suppose it's required only when a transaction includes two or more update statements inside and they all need to done or all need to be rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

If you started a transaction, you must end that transaction, either with a commit or a rollback. Even if you executed a single statement, and even if that single statement failed. In fact, if you start a transaction and don't do anything in that transaction, you need to commit or roll back.

Failure to end a transactions could lead to resource leaks and other concurrency issues (though exact effects depend on the underlying database system and driver).